# Is there a way to use the configuration values from ~/.ssh/config from libssh?

Tags: ssh, openssl, libssh

I'm writing a program which needs to execute remote commands, and it would be very convenient to leverage the configurations which are already present on my machine.  I.e. in my `~/.ssh/config` file, I have servers declared like this:

```
Host my-server
    user my-user
    HostName 88.88.88.888
    port 3456
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_id_rsa
```

Is there a way to leverage what already works, when for instance I type the command:

```
$ ssh my-server
```

from `libssh` so I don't have to re-invent the wheel and parse this config myself?